# How to create notifications even when the app is closed in android

Tags: android

I have a date in following format.

2014-04-01 05:38:59

Here i need to get the notification just one day before the date stored in the database table.

how can I do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to create Service for that which compare current time with Database stored value and if it compared with and got true then create alarm for the particular Time.

Comment: Use an AlarmManager for that. Working example: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html